# java - как запустить .jar с библиотекой LWJGL

Tags: java, lwjgl

если запускаю через `java -jar ...\project.jar`, то вылетает ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/Version
        at com.fe.jade.Window.run(Window.java:31)
        at com.fe.App.main(App.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.lwjgl.Version
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
        ... 2 more
```

Java 21

Если запускаю через `java -Djava.library.path="D:\lwjgl" -jar ...\project.jar`, то вылетает `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class .library.path=D:\lwjgl
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /library/path=D:\lwjgl
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо было у артефакта в **Project Structure** перед компиляцией проекта отметить галочку **Include in project build** и запустить используя `java -jar <путь>\<название>.jar`.